# Factorial number in Rust for learning purposes

Tags: beginner, recursion, rust

I'm currently trying to learn the basics of the Rust programming language, to do this my first piece of code after the classic 'Hello World' was a simple recursive Factorial function.

This is the code:

```
use std::io;

fn factorial(num: i64) -> i64 {
    return if num == 1 {
        1
    }else{
        num * factorial(num - 1)
    }
}

fn trim_newline(s: &mut String){
    if s.ends_with('\n'){
        s.pop();
        if s.ends_with('\r'){
            s.pop();
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut user_input = String::new();
    println!("Welcome to rust-factorial!");
    loop {
        user_input.clear();
        println!("Please enter a number:");
        match io::stdin().read_line(&mut user_input) {
            Ok(_) => (),
            Err(_e) => {
                println!("error: {}", _e);
                continue;
            },
        };
        let num: i64 = match user_input.trim().parse::<i64>() {
            Ok(n) => n,
            Err(_e) => {
                trim_newline(&mut user_input); // remove trailing newline
                println!("'{}' is not a valid number, full error: {}", user_input, _e);
                continue;
            },
        };
        println!("{}! is equal to {}", num, factorial(num));
    }
}
```

I am aware of one major issue with my current approach which is that the biggest number this program can calculate is the 20th number of the sequence. Asking for a number bigger than 20 results in the following error on my machine:

```
Please enter a number:
24
thread 'main' panicked at 'attempt to multiply with overflow', src\main.rs:7:9
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\rust-factorial.exe` (exit code: 101)
```

I'd like to know a few things:

- How can I change this code to be more "rust-like"

  - (by that I mean 'pythonic' but for rust)
- What would the rust approach be for solving the overflow that happens with numbers past 20?

  - (I could either hard-code the limit or something to that effect but I'm curious whether or not there is a guideline about this from a Rust perspective)
- Any and all comments on code quality, readability and potentially efficiency

Comment: Please check the connection between title(&description) and the code presented.

Comment: @greybeard my bad, was confused, will edit this now

Comment: `0!=1`. I think your implementation Will go crazy when you input zero.

Comment: oops, nice catch @slepic will add that case to my function too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Bugs and types

You should think some about what types you want to have as input and output for `factorial`. Negative numbers won't ever work as input, and the output won't be negative, so you should consider using an unsigned integer, like `u64`. Even doing this, though, there's one input that leads to an infinite loop. See if you can find it and fix the function!

### Cleaning up the error handling

```
match io::stdin().read_line(&mut user_input) {
    Ok(_) => (),
    Err(_e) => {
        println!("error: {}", _e);
        continue;
    }
};
```

A variable with a leading underscore tells readers (and linters) that the variable isn't going to be used. Since we use it (with the `println!`), we should just call it `e`.

This error message should probably be in stderr, rather than stdout. This can be done just by changing it to `eprintln!` instead.

When only one branch of a match actually does something, `if let` is both easier to write and understand. So in all, I'd change this part to

```
if let Err(e) = io::stdin().read_line(&mut user_input) {
    eprintln!("error: {}", e);
    continue;
}
```

---

```
let num: i64 = match user_input.trim().parse::<i64>() {
    Ok(n) => n,
    Err(_e) => {
        trim_newline(&mut user_input); // remove trailing newline
        println!("'{}' is not a valid number, full error: {}", user_input, _e);
        continue;
    },
};
```

Same thing with `_e` vs `e`. You're using the variable, so it shouldn't start with an underscore. Also the same thing with `eprintln!`. Errors should be printed to stderr.

Since both branches of the match are used, `if let` is less useful. However, you might check out the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49785136/unwrap-or-continue-in-a-loop) for some ideas for making this look better. For a single use like this, you're probably fine, but if you do this "unwrap or continue" behavior a lot, it can help to encapsulate it.

The `i64` annotations are unnecessary. The compiler has enough information to conclude that the type of `num` is `i64` since it's fed into `factorial`. If you want to keep an annotation for explicitness, that's fine, but only one of `num: i64` and `parse::<i64>` is needed for that.

`trim_newline` seems to be unnecessary. You're parsing `user_input.trim()` anyway, so just show that to the user if there's a parsing error.

```
let num = match user_input.trim().parse() {
    Ok(n) => n,
    Err(e) => {
        eprintln!("'{}' is not a valid number, full error: {}", user_input.trim(), e);
        continue;
    }
};
```

### Using standard tools for formatting and linting

One thing that goes a long way with making your code more readable and idiomatic is running `cargo fmt`. You may need to install it with `rustup component add rustfmt`.

Clippy is another standard tool for catching errors and making your code more idiomatic. It can similarly be installed with `rustup` using `rustup component add clippy`. Running it (with `cargo clippy`) on your program, we get the warning

```
warning: unneeded `return` statement
 --> src/main.rs:4:5
  |
4 | /     return if num == 1 {
5 | |         1
6 | |     }else{
7 | |         num * factorial(num - 1)
8 | |     }
  | |_____^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(clippy::needless_return)]` on by default
  = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#needless_return
help: remove `return`
  |
4 |     if num == 1 {
5 |         1
6 |     }else{
7 |         num * factorial(num - 1)
8 |     }
  |
```

Since the return statement is the last thing in the function, it's not needed since the last expression in the block is always implicitly returned. You can simply remove the `return`.

### Some advice on overflows

The factorial function grows superexponentially, so any fixed-width integer type is going to quickly overflow. Even switching to `u128` only gets you up to an input of 34. The way I see it, you have two choices. Either

- Embrace this. Return an `Option` (or better yet, a `Result`) to indicate that an overflow occurred. Using something like `u64::checked_mul` would be helpful for that.
- Avoid overflow completely (barring memory limits) by using some sort of `BigInt`. The crate [`num_bigint`](https://docs.rs/num-bigint/0.2.6/num_bigint/) has an implementation with everything you'd need here, including parsing, printing, multiplying and subtracting. You should be able to replace `i64` with `BigUint` (or `BigInt`) with only a few conversions from integer literals.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed write-up :) I'll look through it and try to apply it!